# syntax error, unexpected token "@" (View: /data/sites/web/admin/report/rec_revenue.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am Using Laravel and my code was working fine i don't know if this error is because of server or something else. but i guess in blade template it is having trouble converting @php to  i would be happy if you will guide me
my code look like this

```html
<tbody>
@foreach ($arrData as $k => $data)
@php($i = 1)
@php($yearTotal = 0)
@php($futureYearTotal = 0)
@foreach ($data as $k2 => $yd)
   <tr>
   <td><h6><span class="badge bg-light">{{$k}} {{ $k2 }}</span></h6></td>
   <td class="total-amount" align="right">{{ number_format($yd['total']??0, 2, ',', ' ') }}{{ $yd['currency'] }}</td>
   </tr>
@php($yearTotal += $yd['total'])
@endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have more than one PHP lines of code, you can use this syntax:

```blade
@php
   $i = 1;
   $yearTotal = 0;
   $futureYearTotal = 0;
@endphp
```

Comment: "_Since you have more than one PHP lines of code_" Do the lines of code matter? What would be the syntax for one line of code?

Comment: To reply to @brombeer : the syntax *@php()* is valid - even if it is not mentioned in the official documentation - however, as I have also seen, in some circumstances - apparently when *@php()* is nested in other directives - it is not interpreted correctly. In this case, the fact that there are more consecutive lines of pure PHP, better justifies the *@php ..... @endphp* syntax which is more streamlined. Similar situations are mentioned [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/47948)

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that your code was working but only error is coming in the above mentioned code then replace your code with the code given below.

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($arrData as $k => $data)
@php
$i = 1;
$yearTotal = 0;
$futureYearTotal = 0;
@endphp
@foreach ($data as $k2 => $yd)
   <tr>
   <td><h6><span class="badge bg-light">{{$k}} {{ $k2 }}</span></h6></td>
   <td class="total-amount" align="right">{{ number_format($yd['total']??0, 2, ',', ' ') }}{{ $yd['currency'] }}</td>
   </tr>
@php
$yearTotal += $yd['total'];
@endphp
@endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
```